# Is there a Ubuntu for SPARC computer?

Tags: system-installation

Is there a Ubuntu for SPARC computer? My friend like Ubuntu and he want to install on his SPARC (UltraSPARC IV, release 2005).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of, Yes.  There were SPARC ports of two LTS releases: 8.04 and 10.04 server.  After 10.04 however no-one was actively maintaining the ports so that was the last one.  12.04 does not have a SPARC port, and I haven't heard of anyone working on the port.

Theoretically 10.04 server is supported until April 2015, however since no-one appears to be maintaining the SPARC ports it seems unlikely that there will be any updates.  What there is of 10.04 for SPARC is [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ports/releases/10.04/release/).  Scroll down to the bottom for most of the SPARC downloads

It seems unlikely that there would be many people here who have used the SPARC port, but you might ask around the SPARC community to get their thoughts on it.

Answer (score 2):

No, at least -- not a recent release. You can still install 10.04 LTS, which has [SPARC installation images](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ports/releases/10.04/release/) available.

Alternatively, you can try Debian, since Debian is continuously being released for SPARC as well as a [broad range](http://www.debian.org/devel/debian-installer/) of other architectures.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way is to install Ubuntu 10.04, and add Debian repos, then update via those, that would keep things modern, but in effect may remove some things Ubuntu is known for ie branding, design quirks for Debian layouts ie the way gnome is layed out etc...